# ANOVA: Can Block and Factor Be The Same Thing?

Tags: anova

Response = Unique User per URL

Factor = Group by Enrollment Number

Block = Group By Enrollment Number

URLs are for school district, which has varying enrollments

To account for variation in user numbers based on enrollment, I have it blocked when testing other factors.

I also want to test if a URL gets higher users based on Enrollment Group.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

1. Blocking is equivalent to adding control variables in the regression. (That is if you want to regress Y on X, but, add Z as a control variable because you think Z drives both Y and X). So, when you test other factors, then, dividing the total sample into groups by enrollment number is like adding enrollment number as a control variable.
2. ANOVA, which is a way of testing hypotheses about means, requires you to group by values taken by the factor (enrollment number). If you are running ANOVA to test if "enrollment number does affect the number of URL users", then, grouping on the basis of enrollment number is the way to go.